# How can we define a device type without context

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been looking for a way to define if a device is a tablet or not and have found something about checking the shortestside < 600 but it's not working.

```
class FontSizeManager {
  static final FontSizeManager _instance = FontSizeManager._internal();
  final screensize = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.display.size.shortestSide; //this prints 1080
  final bool isMobile = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.shortestSide < 600; //this is also 1080
  FontSizeManager._internal();

  factory FontSizeManager() {
    return _instance;
  }

  double fontSize(double size) {
    if(isMobile) {
      return size;
    } else {
      return size+8;
    }
  }
}
```

From my code above it's only get 1080 which is the resolution of the screen so 600 can't be use.
Also flutter docs saying that 'WidgetsBinding.instance.window' is deprecated. What to use instead?

I want to use the above class for managing the font size of all widgets.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class FontSizeManager {
  static final FontSizeManager _instance = FontSizeManager._internal();
  final double screenSize = SizerUtil.deviceScreenSize;

  late final bool isMobile;

  FontSizeManager._internal() {
    _init();
  }

  factory FontSizeManager() {
    return _instance;
  }

  _init() {
    isMobile = _calculateIsMobile();
  }

  bool _calculateIsMobile() {
    // Adjust this threshold based on your needs
    const double tabletShortestSide = 600;

    return screenSize < tabletShortestSide;
  }

  double fontSize(double size) {
    if (isMobile) {
      return size;
    } else {
      return size + 8;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the "deviceDiagonal" is not available for me in SizerUtil